# NextJs - routing gives 404 error in production

Tags: next.js

we launched our small site in production yesterday (it is a static site generated with NextJS and exported), but we have an issue, the routing works well, but when refreshing a page (except the homepage), it returns a 404 error.
I have tried adding trailSlash to the config, and all the tricks I found here, with no result.
The website is https://www.trisgram.com/

Comment: How are you doing your routing? Can you share the repository? From the looks of it, your routes aren't defined, the frontend UI simply replaces the pages to give the impression of visiting another route. When you refresh at the route, it doesn't exist. With Next.js, each file in the `pages` folder gets assigned its own route. I assume you're breaking out of that convention?

Comment: Hi, it is in a private repo, but, no I am using the conventional page routing of Nextjs, each route is a .tsx file inside the pages folder and I use next/link to navigate between pages, the added query param is because of next-i18n-export.

Comment: Interesting, that query param seems to be interfering with the route. If you take the query param off, you get taken back to the home page.

Comment: Well we found out it could be an issue with apache, and redirecting to the homepage is a quick "fix" we put this afternoon, but of course it is not at all ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be because your trying to render the design before data comes from API, try adding condition for you JSX